# Do ages in Georgia now count from conception?

Tags: united-states, georgia

In Georgia, a person must be at least 15 years old to obtain a learners permit for driving. Historically, this would unambiguously be understood to mean that today, August 16, 2022, a person must have been born on or before August 16, 2007. With the LIFE Act, can this be interpreted to include anyone conceived on or after that date? Could a person conceived on August 16, 2007, and born nine months later on May 16, 2008 (14 years and 3 months ago) obtain a Georgia learners permit today?

Comment: How would you establish the date of conception?

Comment: @MichaelHall Good question. Unless it was a One-Night-Stand, probably not even the parents know exactly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Georgia Code § 40-5-24](https://codes.findlaw.com/ga/title-40-motor-vehicles-and-traffic/ga-code-sect-40-5-24.html) says:

> Any resident of this state who is **at least 15 years of age** may apply to the department for an instruction permit to operate a noncommercial Class C vehicle.

What is “age”?  [According to § 15-11-6](https://codes.findlaw.com/ga/title-15-courts/ga-code-sect-15-11-6.html),

> (a) Except as provided in subsection (b) of this Code section, a child attains a specified age the first second past midnight **on the day of the anniversary of such child's birth.**
>
> (b) A child born on February 29 attains a specified age on March 1 of any year that is not a leap year.

So, you still have to wait until the 15th anniversary *of your birth* to apply for a permit.

Comment: Ahhh, the "Pirates of Penzanze" clause...